# Behavior of JS/CSS from unsecured CDN

Tags: security, ssl, https

When using JS/CSS from unsecured CDN in https page,

***A.*** Some pages block loading js/css, and cause runtime error by short of js code.

***B.*** Some pages do not block loading js/css, pages are shown as entirely insecure contents.

What is the difference of these behaviors?
Even if using same browser (I'm using Chrome 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) in Mac OS X) and seeing same page, behavior changes sometimes...

May some response headers of index.html or so control this behavior?
Anyone know about this?

#### Example:

My friend create page `https://cfn-iot-heatmap.herokuapp.com/`, in before, this page's behavior was like ***A***, contents are totally white out.
In this case, insecure CDN contents are:

- https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js
- https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css

I got source codes of this page and deployed to my heroku repository `https://kinkyujitai.herokuapp.com/`, it is shown like ***B***.
But curious, after I deployed my repository, friend's repository also works like B, showing security warning but shown.

It is very curious, so I want to know the reason of this phenomena...

Answer (score 0):

From a secure (https) origin, you should always include secure elements.

If you don't, browser can block insecure request and/or remove the visual indication of the security.